# ApostropheCMS - how to serve different page in middleware

Tags: express, middleware, apostrophe-cms

I have ApostropheCMS v3 project.
I want to add some middleware inside modules/@apostrophecms/page/index.js.
I believe it sould look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  handlers(self, options) {
    return {
      "@apostrophecms/page:serve": {
        handleCustomLocales(req) {
          try {
            // code will go here
          } catch (_err) {}
        },
```

Let's say that the user opened "/en/contact" page. The contact page from EN locale was served by default.

I want to catch a few exceptions. If user opened "/en-cz/contact" ("/en-**/contact") page - I want to still serve contact page from EN locale. For now, it serves 404 page.

I **don't** want to change the url or redirect user to "/en/contact". How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

First, just a warning: serving identical content for two different URLs without a canonical tag can affect your SEO. If you can't use a redirect (which I would recommend), consider outputting a canonical link tag in this situation.

OK, that being said:

To add true Express middleware, which is what you need here, you want to use Apostrophe's `middleware` feature in any module, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  middleware(self, options) {
    return {
      altLocales: {
        before: '@apostrophecms/i18n',
        middleware(req, res, next) {
          req.path = req.path.replace('/en-cz', '/en');
          req.url = req.url.replace('/en-cz', '/en');
          return next();
        }
      }
    };
  }
};
```

The `before` property schedules this middleware before the middleware installed by the `@apostrophecms/i18n` module, which ensures that `req.locale` is not decided before your middleware has a chance to run.

Of course you can use `options` here to make decisions about what to do based on configuration, and be more careful about ensuring `/en-cz` is only at the start of the path. This is a simple example demonstrating the technique.

Comment: One more thing. After adding custom prefixes I lost the req.locale data. I don't get the locale info, it is probably set to default (en in my case).
Can I set req.locale in this middleware?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, if you reset `req.path` and `req.url` correctly to prefixes that are configured for a locale in middleware that runs before the i18n module's middleware then `req.locale` should get set once that i18n middleware runs.